# Acquiring road labels

Tags: data, labeling, qgis-2

So this is a data acquisition questions:

I have data retrieved from OSM, QGIS2.0.  It's a region of Qatar.  Of the 13 thousand or so roads, I only pulled in about 1 thousand road names.  The roads do have names, I've researched it.  And the names are necessary for a network dataset that will use the street names for routing purposes.

This is just the beginning to my problem, but I'll only ask this question here...
I don't want to bombard this post with multiple inquiries.

Is there a way, or a plugin, or a data source somewhere I do not know about that will let me "append" road names to my current data I already have?  I have already manipulated what I have so I really don't want to hunt down another source unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks,
Logan

Answer (score 1):

If you save your Openstreetmap data to a spatialite database, you can freely edit the data locally by adding the names to the streets that have none in the dataset. The reason why they have no names is simply that the bing satellite imagery does not show street names.

In the layer properties, fields tab, you can hide all other columns so that only the names field will remain. With that, adding the names will be much quicker. Nethertheless, 12.000 missing names will take some time.

Comment: That is what I was worried about...

Comment: I have brought the data into ArcDesktop and I am creating a network dataset for routing roads in Qatar.  As the routes aren't even working properly as is, I am afraid to invest the time in manually editing each feature when there is a chance that the spatial connectivity of each feature may be non-existent

Comment: I wasn't sure if QGIS had a way to label features based on the OSM or another open layer... I didn't think it'd be that easy. But it would be very cool if it did haha

Comment: I don't think Qatar has road network data published as Open Data. And if so, at least I am not able to read it... If you have a layer with more street names, you could spatially connect label points to street lines.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a layer or feature class containing labels... That's the big issue.  You're right otherwise, I could just spatially join the tables and viola.  This seems like an area that I will have to just spend time creating the data.  If only there were ways to access obscure data like these for free!!

Comment: Thanks for the responses... Maybe someone here will see this and say, "Hey, I created a road feature class with associated road names if you want a copy"...
Highly doubtful though...

Comment: Google and Bing layers have some more street names, but also far from complete.

Comment: I did see those... How would you just extract the road names from a Google or Bing layer though?
I couldn't figure out how to download the data with road names.

Comment: You would have to do it manually: Load G*** or b*** background to the OSM data, click on a street that has a name in the background but not in the data, add name. It would not be 12.000, so does not take that much time.